# Problems installing MYSQL-python-1.2.3 for Python 2.7 on Snow Leopard

Tags: python, mysql, macos

I downloaded the tar.gz file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/

unzip, then ran python setup.py install, but it said it requires setuptools module, so I downloaded setuptools from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files The file was setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg  (md5) then I ran

```
sh setuptools-0.6c9-py2.4.egg
```

Then back to mysql-python-1.2.3 folder, I ran

```
sudo setup.py install
```

Just for the record, here is the installation log:

```
MacBook-Pros-MacBook-Pro:MySQL-python-1.2.3 2 macbookpro$ python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
warning: no files found matching 'GPL'
writing manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/_mysql.o -g -Os -arch x86_64 -fno-common -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/local/mysql/include/my_config.h:1069:1: warning: "HAVE_WCSCOLL" redefined
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:8,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:881:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
gcc-4.0 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -g -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient_r -lz -lm -lmygcc -o build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/_mysql.so -arch x86_64
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/_mysql.so -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/_mysql_exceptions.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/release.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb/times.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/_mysql_exceptions.py to _mysql_exceptions.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py to connections.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py to CLIENT.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants/CR.py to CR.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants/ER.py to ER.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py to FIELD_TYPE.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py to FLAG.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py to REFRESH.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/converters.py to converters.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py to cursors.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/release.py to release.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/times.py to times.pyc
creating stub loader for _mysql.so
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/_mysql.py to _mysql.pyc
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/EGG-INFO
writing build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/EGG-INFO/native_libs.txt
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating dist
creating 'dist/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-fat.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-fat.egg
Copying MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-fat.egg to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding MySQL-python 1.2.3 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-fat.egg
Processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.3
Finished processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.3
```

Then in my Django project folder I ran python manage.py runserver

but it failed, returned this:

```
Validating models...
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function inner_run at 0x106df70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 48, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 22, in get_validation_errors
    from django.db import models, connection
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 32, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/macbookpro/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-fat.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/macbookpro/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-fat.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Has anybody had similar problem before? Can anybody help, please? Thank you

**Update**

```
file /Users/macbookpro/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-fat.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
```

returned:

```
/Users/macbookpro/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-fat.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

and

```
file `which python`
```

returned:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python (for architecture ppc):    Mach-O executable ppc
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python (for architecture i386):   Mach-O executable i386
```

**Update 1**

Based on the information above, I thought the error was caused by python installed in i386 while MySQLdb in x86_64 (whatever that means...) So I tried to build MySQLdb with arch i386 using technique shown in this tutorial: http://cd34.com/blog/programming/python/mysql-python-and-snow-leopard/, but it didn't work, then I tried to build it with x86_64, does not work either.

Here is my terminal history:

build with i386:

```
ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386' python setup.py build
```

returned:

```
running build
running build_py
creating build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/_mysql.o -g -Os -arch x86_64 -fno-common -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/local/mysql/include/my_config.h:1069:1: warning: "HAVE_WCSCOLL" redefined
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:8,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:881:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
gcc-4.0 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -g -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient_r -lz -lm -lmygcc -o build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/_mysql.so -arch x86_64
```

Then ran the setup:

```
ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386' python setup.py install
```

result:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
warning: no files found matching 'GPL'
writing manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb
running build_ext
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/_mysql.so -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/_mysql_exceptions.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/release.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.7/MySQLdb/times.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/_mysql_exceptions.py to _mysql_exceptions.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py to connections.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py to CLIENT.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/constants/CR.py to CR.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/constants/ER.py to ER.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py to FIELD_TYPE.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py to FLAG.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py to REFRESH.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/converters.py to converters.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py to cursors.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/release.py to release.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/times.py to times.pyc
creating stub loader for _mysql.so
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/_mysql.py to _mysql.pyc
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/EGG-INFO
writing build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/EGG-INFO/native_libs.txt
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-i386.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-i386.egg
Copying MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-i386.egg to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding MySQL-python 1.2.3 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-i386.egg
Processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.3
Finished processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.3
```

Then I ran python to check if MySQLdb installed correctly:

```
MacBook-Pros-MacBook-Pro:MySQL-python-1.2.3 2 macbookpro$ python
Python 2.7 (r27:82508, Jul  3 2010, 20:17:05) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-i386.egg/_mysql.py:3: UserWarning: Module _mysql was already imported from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-i386.egg/_mysql.pyc, but /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.3 2 is being added to sys.path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/macbookpro/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-i386.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/macbookpro/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-i386.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Then since it doesn't work, I desperately tried to build it with -arch x86_64, but does not work either:

```
ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' python setup.py build

running build
running build_py
creating build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -g -Os -arch x86_64 -fno-common -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/local/mysql/include/my_config.h:1069:1: warning: "HAVE_WCSCOLL" redefined
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:8,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:881:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
gcc-4.0 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -g -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient_r -lz -lm -lmygcc -o build/lib.macosx-10.3-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.so -arch x86_64
```

then installation

```
ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' python setup.py install

Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.3
Finished processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.3
```

Then again I tried to check in python

```
MacBook-Pros-MacBook-Pro:MySQL-python-1.2.3 2 macbookpro$ python
```

which failed again

```
>>> import MySQLdb
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-x86_64.egg/_mysql.py:3: UserWarning: Module _mysql was already imported from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-x86_64.egg/_mysql.pyc, but /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.3 2 is being added to sys.path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/macbookpro/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/macbookpro/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Is there anywhere I may have done wrong?

**Update 2**

Running this code in python (if it may help you investigating in anyway)

```
>>> import math
>>> import sys
>>> math.log(sys.maxint, 2)
30.999999999328196
```

Thank you

Comment: Please show us output of: `file /Users/macbookpro/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.3-fat.egg-tmp/_mysql.so` and `file \`which python\``

Comment: I've included it, so, does it tell anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is probably that you have installed a 64-bit only version of the MySQL client libraries.  Note that the `MySQLdb` build process (in `setup_posix.py`) queries the `mysql_build` command to find the various flags that were used to build the MySQL client libraries and augment the building of the `MySQLdb` extension module.  Your Python instance and your MySQL client libraries must have at least one common architecture.  Either install a version of MySQL client that includes 32-bit Intel (`-arch i386`) or install a 64-bit version of Python 2.7.  It is for reasons like this that I recommend installing a complete Django solution (or at least a Python and MySQL solution) using `MacPorts` to avoid such incompatibilities.

Comment: Installed 64-bit version of Python 2.7 and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a 32-bit mysql with a 64-bit python (which is standard in Snow Leopard), or vice versa.

If this is not the case, then look out on the DMG MySQL came in to find the correct MySQL-python. Look [here](http://cd34.com/blog/programming/python/mysql-python-and-snow-leopard/) for further information.

**Update**
I missed something... is your Python installation 32 or 64 bit? If unsure, check with this code:

```
import math
import sys
math.log(sys.maxint, 2)
```

I fear you may have somehow missed the “matched” combination of the three programs.

Comment: The gcc statements are also passing along `-arch x86_64` (64-bit) instead of `-arch i386` (32-bit).

Comment: Tried both arch x86_64 and i386, but didn't work (see my update above), any thoughts?